# Sharepoint 2010: Get the List's / Library's IRM properties

Tags: list, sharepoint, properties

I have been struggling with something lately.

Does anybody know where I could pragmatically find a list's IRM settings?

I am talking about these properties:

[image]

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been directed to the answer (down the page you can find the way you can access them from 2010) :

http://sharepoint.nauplius.net/2013/07/using-powershell-to-manage-sharepoint-information-rights-management-settings/

Does anybody know how to do this:

string print = list.RootFolder.Properties["vti_irm_IrmPrint"].ToString();
with the client object model?